# Google Trends for a Website

Tags: google-trends

Some time ago Google Trends for websites did make possible to get statistics about sites. For example http://trends.google.com/websites?q=wikipedia.org showed the chart about the historical series of unique visitors for wikipedia.org site.

Note that [this page](http://www.google.com/intl/en/trends/websites/help/index.html) explaining Google Trends for website is currently available.

Now that Google Trends for websites has been merged with Google Trends, is it still possible to get the same statistics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a few weeks ago it was "[spring cleaned](http://googleblog.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/more-spring-cleaning.html)" as Google likes to put it:

> We've merged Insights for Search into a revamped Google Trends. You
>   can now see search trends and compare search volume patterns across
>   specific regions, categories, time frames and properties in a single
>   place: google.com/trends. **We will no longer support Trends for
>   Websites, which allowed people to compare traffic to and audiences of
>   different websites.**

You could use one of the many other stats sites like [Alexia](http://www.alexa.com), thought the data will be a bit different. And less pretty.

Answer (score -1):

I have used Google trends more than google keyword/Adword tool for my site BrightVerge. I have been successful in SEO with Google insights and some other tools also. Geographic, year wise trends shows good results with god traffic. One can select some 2 words phrases and few one word keyword to get permanent good traffic for your website.

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question. Could you rewrite your answer to be clearer?